# Why do I get notifications about "ghost" answers?

Tags: support, bug, notifications, deleted-answers

I experienced this 2 or 3 times to me recently : I get notifications in my StackExchange Inbox about answers to questions I asked, however when I go see the question (or follow the link in the notification) I am not seeing the answer, in this precise case there is no answer at all.

I can see the beginning of the answer in the notification, but no answer in the question page.  I know it can last for at least 10 minutes, but usually I see the answer on the next day (at least for the two times it already happend to me).

I currently have the problem on one of my questions, but I don't think I should share the link as this could be considered as "view-seeking".

I tried refreshing my browser cache, clearing it, logging in and out of StackOverflow, does not change anything.

As it is usually really convenient to be able to discuss live with the person who answers, using comments or opening a discussion in the chat, in order to give additionnal details about the question or ask additionnal details about the answer, I would like to know if there is any way to avoid this latency? Or is it only an internal StackOverflow caching policy matter?

Comment: Posting a link to a suspect can't really be considered "view-seeking". The "problem" might be that the answers were deleted.

Comment: It could be that the answer got deleted before you viewed the notification. A 10k user could check for you if you provided links.

Comment: Here is the link, with the answer ID : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223173/child-dependant-field-in-abstract-class-with-djangos-orm/13223329#13223329

Comment: @pistache That answer was in fact posted 35 minutes ago and deleted by its owner 19 minutes ago.

Comment: Yep, deleted answer. http://i.imgur.com/1RFSH.png

Comment: Okay, sorry, I thought there was a notification for this as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Xeo If the poster wanted to delete the answer, wouldn't it be agsinst their wishes to post a sceenshot?

Comment: It's a special scary Halloween thing.